# Resume big files without FTP access, howto?

Tags: download

What is the best way to download [this update](http://www.o2online.de/nw/support/downloads/software/htc/htcdesire/htc-desire.html)?

Last time it was stopped in the middle and resuming seems not possible with Internet Explorer. Any better way?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a "Download Manager" you don't state your OS so here is a suggestion that is free, runs on windows and claims to support broken/interrupted downloads.

[Fresh Download](http://www.freshdevices.com/freshdown.html)

Comment: He did mention that resuming downloads with Internet Explorer does not seem to be possible.  IE9 Beta can resume downloads, I think.  It has a download manager, but I have never had the need to resume a download since I started using it.

Comment: @gentlesea: Right-click the link you wish to download, do "Copy link location", then paste it into the download manager.

Comment: I like GetRight (but it is pay), I hear many using FDM http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/  One thing to remember is the server must allow resuming, so if the server isn't configured to allow it all downloads will start from the beginning.  (Personally, I don't know why they wouldn't allow resuming.  I assume it is to prevent download managers from opening 4 or 8 connections at once and downloading files faster than they want.)